# array.push is missing the following properties from type

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am having an issue with my register page in IONIC.

Right now I am using a data.json file where all the data is stored, and i want to create another user (member) in here. For creating a member I only need a bit of the users information (name, mail and password) but the user info exists of way more data.

The error I'm getting is that my arrayPush is missing the following properties (the ones that I don't want to add yet and rather leave empty).

This is my TS

```
import {Component, Input, AfterViewInit, Output, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {AlertController, ModalController, NavParams} from '@ionic/angular';
import data from '../../../../data.json'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {
  @Input() fullName = '';
  @Input() email = '';
  @Input() password = '';
  @Input() repeatPassword = '';

  messageString: string;
  today = new Date();

  constructor(private router: Router, private alertController: AlertController) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onRegister() {
    //Grab data from HTML inputs and check if valid. If not popup.
    if (this.fullName === '') {this.messageString = "You didn't enter a name.";this.errorMessage();return;}
    if (this.email === '') {this.messageString = "You didn't enter an mail address.";this.errorMessage();return;}
    if (this.password === '') {this.messageString = "You didn't enter a password.";this.errorMessage();return;}
    if (this.password != this.repeatPassword) {this.messageString = "The passwords don't match.";this.errorMessage();return;}

    var firstname = this.fullName.split(" ")[0];
    var lastname = this.fullName.split(" ").pop();
    
    //save all data to JSON
    (data).members.push({ 
      fullname: this.fullName,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      mail: this.email,
      password: this.password,
    });
    
    //Redirect to homepage.
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home').then(r => {});
  }
  
  // Alert emails dont match
  async errorMessage() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      cssClass: 'alerts',
      header: 'ERROR',
      message: this.messageString,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Okay',
          cssClass: 'yes'
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present();
  }

}
```

and this is my data.json

```
{
  "members": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "gender": "0",
      "fullname": "X X",
      "firstname": "X",
      "infix": "",
      "lastname": "X",
      "number": "06-12345678",
      "mail": "user@company.com",
      "image": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EHMN4bVWoAUXhUz.jpg",
      "password": "admin1",
      "birthdate": "14-07-2001",
      "country": "Netherlands",
      "address": "Testweg 1a",
      "state": "Noord Holland",
      "city": "Amsterdam",
      "zip": "1234BC",
      "subscription": "26 Dec. 2020"
    }
  ]
}
```

I only want to fill the following JSON objects so far for a new user
fullname, firstname, lastname, email, password

Comment: Not really related to your question, but you won't be able to change the JSON file in the file system just by pushing to the array... In fact I don't think there is any way to modify the file content, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface:** I'm not entirely sure what the overall intention of the code is, but the answer below deals with the type issue you mentioned. But the code shown pushes to a data array that was *read*, initially, from `data.json`, and doesn't (in the code shown) seem to save that array anywhere. As [JSON Derulo points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70245193/array-push-is-missing-the-following-properties-from-type/70245367#comment124174152_70245193), pushing to that array has no effect on the `data.json` file, just the in-memory array.

---

It sounds like TypeScript is inferring the type of `data` from `data.json`, since you aren't giving a type explicitly. TypeScript won't (can't) infer that a property should be optional. To do that, you have to specify it.

There are several ways you can do that.

- List all the properties yourself in a type definition.
- List all the optional properties in a type definition, allowing the other (required) properties to be inferred.
- List all the required properties in a type definition, allowing the other (optional) properties to be inferred.

Of those, the last one seems most useful to what you describe:

```typescript
import sampleData from "../../../../data.json";

type MemberType =
    Partial<typeof sampleData["members"][number]>
    & Pick<
        typeof sampleData["members"][number],
        "fullname" | "firstname" | "lastname" | "mail" | "password"
    >;

const data: typeof sampleData & {members: MemberType[]} = sampleData;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGBbADgGwKYBF5XjAvDAN4BQMMARIuogEboBOEFAXDANpnnFfeUCWAE1YwAjABpe3CgHN0YQYxEUADBUl9yFAGYBXVKjBJ0ygBoxT6qVu38mUI9TNXNAsLYAeyl5oqp40I4mbBSWGr5gunRKISoAbAC0ogBMAMwALACscQDsABw+fFTw-KjKuhCMAAKgKPBgAJ4AdLWF0vyI8HLKABZQUMgQLAD0w8i0EE1QAO4dMi0giMPUgvzwwwCiABIAsgBy6bQAagDqIACCAKqmPZcAXk0AVsgybVrIARDTIAzCIfCCRD8MCiN6UWh2KA9QQ4YKUUTpBIqHIJZIqFSg8JFUC6MBQBgNZR7dBQxj+BTMLHSAGCBjoCDMEIAFXpM3QMjE8DBFGgsKJIB+ghgWxABnqwipWmA-CghJC50Q0EYMMQ3Lu-GQyhSGQAQgBhbkQXQTYAMDVQfjgZTJOIwTDoYBNGBotEUKQAXy4AF0SO6ANwkEiy5DoGA7Gj0BhMhohghSAAK8AYFvgqAAPMH0CBtHAkGgsDh4OwqBHGMwvexItEGF6AHxSABkMHj-GAAGs09ZuJns7mUBhsLhi9Rq+XK1FI17JdI9AYghQYAAfSi2ezzpeUfyBYwL5fFUq7ygfBnfX5uvi1gMkUCQWAw3BsHs5hD9gu4GBNogjyNDMOlqMxug7Beu6BB9vmg7wFe97wE035lk0yAVD0AAUpB8LOhjGCEXhUqu27UDhbRbg42GULhUidKURFUseXyCjRvoAJRAA)

That lets TypeScript infer the type from `data.json`, but then we make all properties optional, and then override the ones that should be required with their original non-optional definition.